# remove white spaces from the list

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading from a CSV file and appending the rows into a list. There are some white spaces that are causing issues in my script. I need to remove those white spaces from the list which I have managed to remove. However can someone please advise if this is the right way to do it?

```
ip_list = []

with open('name.csv') as open_file:
    read_file = csv.DictReader(open_file)
    for read_rows in read_file:
        ip_list.append(read_rows['column1'])
        ip_list = list(filter(None, ip_list))

print(ip_list)
```

Or a function would be preferable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to read a csv file and store in list.

```
L=[]                            #Create an empty list for the main array
for line in open('log.csv'):    #Open the file and read all the lines
    x=line.rstrip()             #Strip the \n from each line
    L.append(x.split(','))      #Split each line into a list and add it to the
                                #Multidimensional array
print(L)
```

For example this csv file would produce an output like

```
This is the first line, Line1
This is the second line, Line2
This is the third line, Line3
```

This,

```
List = [('This is the first line', 'Line1'),
        ('This is the second line', 'Line2'),
        ('This is the third line', 'Line3')]
```

Because csv means **comma seprated values** you can filter based on commas

Comment: I want to read a specific column but it's appending the entire content including the white spaces.

Would a function be helpful? I cannot get this function to run.

def remove_spaces(ip_list):
    ip_list = list(filter(None, ip_list))
    return ip_list